# Creating a chart w/ variable date range-where data comes from access and min and max date are selected from drop downs from dame data source

Tags: c#, datetime, data-binding, charts, type-conversion

I'm seeming to have run into an issue in creating s stock chart.

I have a simple data set in Access of 1 stock, with price data (double) and a each day listed as date/time.

So when I load the data source into C#, the data come into my chart smoothly. But instead of seeing all the data (from 1980-present), I just want to see the data shown on the graph to default to 1yr ago - present, and thereafter I want be able to change the range of data that's shown.

I put in to 2 date/time pickers, 1 for beginning, 1 for the end range.

but when I declare the dates picked- and set them to a variable name- then have the chart x axis min and max set to those respective values, I run into a 'type is not double' issue. Even though the chart axis is set to date/time...

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Can you post your code please?